# OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications using Python 3.4, cannot import name 'SERVICE_ACCOUNT'

Tags: python, oauth, google-api, ubuntu-12.04, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to implement 'Server to Server' OAuth authentication in my Python 3.4 application to work with Google Cloud Storage. So, in general it is described on this page [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts)

But there's an error while I'm running my script:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "my_script.py", line 4, in
>   
>       from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py",
>   line 31, in 
>       from oauth2client.client import SERVICE_ACCOUNT
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'SERVICE_ACCOUNT'

So, here's my code:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('./keyfile.json', scopes)

http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
service = build('storage', 'v1', http=http_auth)
```

If you would be so kind to help me with it, it would be great! It's the one of my first scripts on a Python language, and I'm a newbie both in Python and in Linux worlds, so I can miss something very obvious.

If it is important, my OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show the rest of the error message

Comment: @barny, oh, sorry, my bad. I've updated the error text in the question, so that's all that I got when running the script

Comment: Have you tried searching the google support forums https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-api-python-client

Comment: @barny, yeah, I've tried to find something similar there, but haven't found anything that helped me. But maybe you're right and I should ask there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that `google-api-python-client` installed `oauth2client` version 1.5.2, but it actually needed version 2.0.0. So, your `pip install oauth2client --upgrade` is what saved you.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! It really looks like a probable reason of that behavior, but after your answer I've tried to uninstall `oauth2client`, then ran `google-api-python-client` installation. And, after that, `pip show oauth2client` showed me a '2.0.0' version. Is there something that I don't understand right?

Comment: This is actually what I needed to have pip install in order to make it work: `google-api-python-client==1.5.0 oauth2client==2.0.0.post1`

Comment: thank you! I think I should trust to your experience and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, somehow it started to work. Sorry, I know that self-answering is not very nice, but I spent 2 days with this problem.

So, as I mentioned before, I'm a newbie in a Linux world. I think, `oauth2client` reinstallation helped me. I tried to downgrade it to 1.5.2 version with `pip install -Iv oauth2client==1.5.2`, and then after another fail just ran `pip install oauth2client --upgrade`.

Also I replaced `apiclient` lib with `googleapiclient`, so my first string now looking like `from googleapiclient.discovery import build`

And now it's working, I even don't know why.

Sorry for self-answering again.

Comment: Nothing wrong with self answering. Thank you for sharing your solution

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues where I was getting `cannot import name xxxx` error.  It turn out I had old *.pyc files in my environment from an older oauth2client version.  Even though I updated to the lastest oauth2client version, the *.pyc files were getting used when I tried to run.  I simply deleted the oauth2client *.pyc files and then reran my program without any issues.